# About the integral domain $R=\{\frac{a}{b}\in\mathbb{Q}|(b,2)=(b,3)=1\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I know that the invertible elements in $R$ are of the form $\frac{a}{b}$, satisfying $(a,2)=(a,3)=(b,2)=(b,3)=1$.

Could someone explain how to find the set of irreductible elements of $R$? And how do I know if R is a UFD?

Thanks!

Comment: Is $(p,q)$ the gcd? If so then is this even well defined? For example, $3 = \frac{3}{1} \not\in R$ but $\frac{15}{5} \in R$. Even if you disallow $1$ in denominator you have examples like $\frac{6}{2} \notin R$ but $\frac{15}{5} \in R$

Comment: You're right, there must be some problem with the definition of $R$, but surprisingly that's what it's written in the paper. It would be well defined if the condition was $(b,2)=1$ OR $(b,3)=1$, right? I will comment it to my teacher in case there's a similar exercise in the exam, though.

Comment: Still no, as in this case $\frac{6}{6} \not\in R$ but $\frac{15}{15} \in R$, since $(2,15) = 1$.

Comment: Wow, true. There must be an error then. I'll take it into account, thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ring you are describing is what one would call a *localization* of $\mathbb{Z}$. This entails that we invert element of $\mathbb{Z}$ that is not divisible by $2$ or $3$. Let
$$R=\left\{\frac{a}{b}\in \mathbb{Q}~\middle|~ (a,b)=(2,b)=(3,b)=1\right\}.$$

We start by identifying the invertible elements of $R$. Since $R$ is a subring of $\mathbb{Q}$, if an element $\frac{a}{b}\in R$ has an inverse in $R$, then it must be the same inverse it has in $\mathbb{Q}$ (namely $\frac{b}{a}$). It hence follows that $$\frac{a}{b}\in R^*\Leftrightarrow\frac{b}{a}\in R\Leftrightarrow(2,a)=(3,a)=1.$$
Hence the only non-invertible elements of $R$ are given by
$$R\backslash R^*=\left\{\frac{a2^m3^n}{b}\middle |\text{ with } a,b,2,3 \text{ pairwise coprime, and } m,n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}\right\}.$$
Where the irreducible elements are exactly those such that $m=1$ and $n=0$, or $m=0$ and $n=1$.

Now in our description of $R\backslash R^*$ we have already shown that $R$ is a UFD. This also follows from the fact that $R$ is a PID, it's only prime ideals being $(0),(2),(3)$.

Comment: When you say the elements in $R \backslash R^{*}$ are of the form $\frac{a2^{n}3^{m}}{b}$, which I understood well, you are assuming that $a$ and $b$ are two arbitrary elements of $R$, right? I mean, is it necessary that $a$ and $b$ are the same ones that appear in the description of $R^{*}$?

Comment: Maybe it is very quick to deduce, but how do you saw that $(0),(2)$ and $(3)$ are the unique ideals in $R$? I know that if this happens, $R$ is a PID, because every ideal is principal, and that this entails that $R$ is a UFD.

Comment: To answer your first question: $a,b$ are integers that must be coprime with each other and also with $2$ and $3$, so that $\frac{a}{b}\in R^*$. 
As for the second question, take any $\frac{a}{b}\in R$. If $(a,2)=(a,3)=1$ then it is a unit. If not, the element is contained in $(2)$ or $(3)$. You can use this to show that any generator for a prime ideal must, up to multiplication by units, either be $2$ or $3$.